Проблемы со звуком в SIP транках после миграции ms/windows с 2012R2 на 2016
имеется сервер телефонии Asterisk (дистрибутив FreePBX), установленный в виртуальной машине Hyper-V в кластере, версия ОС - 2012R2, в такой конфигурации всё работает нормально но после того, как я обновил один из узлов кластера до Windows Server 2016, то при миграции ASterisk на этот хост стали возникать проблемы со звуком в SIP транках, причем только при входящих звонках, провайдеры разные, один транк идет напрямую через отдельный VLAN, другой - через общий интернет (провайдер в другом городе), так что дело именно в версии ОС хоста, есть какие-то мнения на этот счёт?
